# Convert WMS to polygon keeping html table on QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

I have imported a WMS from the Italian cadastre. The layer I am interested in is Mappe (maps), which is a queryable layer. When I identify the features of one of the "polygons" (I know the term is inappropriate, WMS being more akin to raster on the client side), I have this kind of results:

[image]

To my untrained eye, that "CP.CadastralZoning", whatever it is, seems very much like a data table. I was wondering if there is any way to polygonise the WMS level "Mappe", based on the values in "CP.CadastralZoning"?

It is probably a very stupid questions, but I have yet to find a way to do that.

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: In this instance, as you have  an INSPIRE view service, there should also be a download service, either atom, or WFS